# Conditional with an arbitrary number of conditions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am wondering how I should implement this:
I am looking to print out strings that contains substrings contained in a list (the 'keywords' list). However, I how would I write out the conditional such that it checks the string that contains *every* word from the list? The list has an arbitrary number of keywords.

In this case, my keywords and xml file are extracted from a config file. The xml file is [this](http://www.deadstock.ca/sitemap_products_1.xml). for each "URL" tag, I am printing only the strings in the "loc" tags that matches my keywords.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from config import user_config
import re

# BeautifulSoup - Links and Variants

print("Starting Scrape...")

selected_size = user_config.size
url = user_config.url
req = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
keywords = user_config.keywords

soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'xml')

soup.prettify()

inventory_url = []


for item in soup.find_all('url'):
    inventory_url.append(item.find('loc').text)

print(inventory_url)

for item in inventory_url:
    if keywords[0] in item and keywords[1] in item:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the builtin [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) which checks that *all* elements/substrings in the `keywords` list are contained by the current `item`:

```
for item in inventory_url:
    if all(kw in item for kw in keywords):
        print(item)
```